# Is there downside replacing all remember(value) with remember { derivedStateOf { value } }?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

As in https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects, we have `derivedStateOf` which helps prevent unnecessary Recomposition.

With that, it makes me think, should we always use `derivedStateOf` instead of `remember(value)` as below?

```
// Instead of using
remember(value1) { ... }

// Use
remember { derivedStateOf {value1} }
```

Doing so will also ensure we don't recompose the function that contains the mutableState, but just all the composable functions using that mutableState.

Is there any downside of using `derivedStateOf` as opposed to `remember(value)`?

Comment: See blog post [Plumbing data with derived state in Compose](https://dev.to/zachklipp/plumbing-data-with-derived-state-in-compose-53ka) from Zach Klippenstein, maybe it can help you. But, for short, I would use remember in composable functions and derived state in view models.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended that you replace them all. If the object is re assigned, use remember. If the object content changes, use derivedstateof

If you replace them all with derivedStateOf, object changes will not be detected

Answer (score 0):

`remember` is more flexible in some situations:

1. You can have `mutableState` inside, which can be updated between reconfigurations and reset to the original value when `value1` (or other keys) have changed.
2. There may be a situation where you only need to update the value when some of the states used in the computation change, not any of them, in which case you can specify them in `remember`.

On the other hand, `derivedStateOf` also has its advantages:

1. It doesn't cause recomposition unless the result of the computation has actually changed.
2. It can be used outside the composite function, for example in a view model.

In general, if using `derivedStateOf` gives the expected behavior, you should prefer it over `remember`.

Answer (score 0):

`derivedStateOf` is for observing a change or or a property change in `State`.

if **value1** in both cases is a class that is not `State` `derivedStateOf` won't update

```
@Composable
private fun DerivedStateOfExample() {

    var numberOfItems by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    val count = numberOfItems

    val rememberedCount = remember(count) {
        count
    }

    val derivedCountWithoutState by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            count
        }
    }

    val derivedCountWithState by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            numberOfItems
        }
    }

    // Use derivedStateOf when a certain state is calculated or derived from other state objects.
    // Using this function guarantees that the calculation will only occur whenever one
    // of the states used in the calculation changes.
    val derivedStateMax by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            numberOfItems > 5
        }
    }

    val newMax = remember(count > 5) {
        count
    }

    val derivedStateMin by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            numberOfItems > 0
        }
    }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp)) {

        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            Text(
                text = "Items: $numberOfItems\n" +
                        "derivedCountWithoutState: $derivedCountWithoutState\n" +
                        "derivedCountWithState: $derivedCountWithState\n" +
                        "newMax:$newMax\n" +
                        "rememberedCount:$rememberedCount, count: $count",
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            IconButton(onClick = { numberOfItems++ }) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "add")
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
            IconButton(onClick = { if (derivedStateMin) numberOfItems-- }) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Remove, contentDescription = "remove")
            }
        }


        if (derivedStateMax) {
            Text("Can't be more than 5 items", color = Color(0xffE53935))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

derivedCountWithState won't update because it doesn't observe a state. Same goes for derivedStateMax when the value was not derived from `numberOfItems` but `count > 5`

Also `newMax` is updated when when `remember(count > 5)` turns from false to true. This is where derivedStateOf comes handy, you can check change in each update of `State` with a condition.

Comment: This is a great example. Thanks.